# Install WIN7.1 SDK Visual Studio Tools for XP Target

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio

I have a project a need to build for a customer running XP machines. I am running VS17. I have downloaded the Win7.1 SDK, which supports XP. However, when I go to install it, I get a message that I don't have the correct .NET framework installed. Specifically, it says "Some SDK components require the RTM.NET Framework 4." Specifically, the Build Tools option is greyed out, which I need to build my project. However, I already have Framework 4.0 installed. Any idea how I can get this working?

[image: SDK Install Pic]

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that you have Windows 10 x64, normally the setup is blocked by:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\Version

Try modifying the values (both of them) temporarily to 4.0.30319 and the setup will let you continue. Run regedit as admin or you are not gonna be able to make the change.

If you have x86 Windows, the registry key normally is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\